# Explicit relation between variance( or standard daviation) and x ( the values taken by the random variable)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

So I am trying to find the relationship between the variance or the standard deviation and the values taken by a random variable.

I am trying to put a definition, so  fro example :   for any $x$  value  from a normal distribution  $N(\mu,\sigma)$, we have  $x=$some thing in term of $\sigma$ and  $\mu$.

I think $\sigma $ here plays a major role than $\mu$, since the range of the values taken around the mean is related to the variance and not the vlaue of the mean.

Is this notion some thing popular   and I am  missing it?  If not, can some one please help me  drawing such definition?

Thank you in  advance.

Comment: You're talking about the density?  But the density of the normal at $x$ is $\frac 1{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac {(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$.  I mean, that's the definition.  Were you looking for something else?

Comment: @lulu  yes I agree this is for normal distribution, but i am searching for a general relation between x and  sigma, whatever the distribution is .

Comment: But that is obviously not possible (unless I misunderstand).  Suppose you want $\mu=0,\sigma =1$.  I can do that with a normal or with a uniform (or pretty much anything else you name).